# Apache Spark SQL read and write Cassandra TTL

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

How does spark sql reads apache cassandra data ttl with Dataframe (Spark Sql).
I don't find any example?
Can i get an example?

My previous question was on rdd Does Spark: [Spark get ttl column from cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55259169/spark-get-ttl-column-from-cassandra)

But now the query is for Dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The Spark Cassandra Connector doesn't support TTL and WriteTime in DataFrame API. You can track [JIRA SPARKC-528](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/SPARKC-528) for progress.

You can read TTL and/or WriteTime using the RDD API (best with [mapper to case class](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/4_mapper.md)), and then convert into DataFrame.

Update, September 2020th: Support for TTL & WriteTime for Dataframes was released as part of [SCC 2.5.0 release](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all).